# highchart - display value in xaxis as the value I get from the chart data as is without conversion

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I wanted to get data and display the x value of it as is what I get is what I want to display, somethimes I dont know the data when the chart uploading (I get it after a while from the server)

the problem highchart display the value in the xaxis as datetime,

attached jsfiddle that in the xaxis I dont want any conversion I want to display the values as "08:00" "09:00" and so on..

https://jsfiddle.net/4scqnpy5/

Highchart convert it to 00:00:00:001 00:00:00:002  00:00:00:003

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

```
    scrollbar: {
        barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        barBorderRadius: 7,
        barBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        buttonBorderRadius: 7,
        rifleColor: 'yellow',
        trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
        trackBorderWidth: 1,
        trackBorderColor: 'silver',
        trackBorderRadius: 7
    },
    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'hours',
        data: [
            ["New York", 100],
            ["09:00", 200],
            ["Pariz", 300],
            ["1100", 150]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that's supposed to represent time?  If so, you need to format the data into a Date object with `Date.UTC()`

```js
 Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        scrollbar: {
            barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            barBorderRadius: 7,
            barBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
            buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            rifleColor: 'yellow',
            trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
            trackBorderWidth: 1,
            trackBorderColor: 'silver',
            trackBorderRadius: 7
        },
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'hours',
            data: [
              [Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 8, 00), 100], 
              [Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 9, 00), 200], 
              [Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 10, 00), 300],
              [Date.UTC(0, 0, 0, 11, 00), 150]
            ]
        }]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 900px; min-width: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: yes this is in case I have time but what about strings as "New York"

Comment: then you look for category axis - which is not supported in a stockchart. You  need a regular chart with categories and enabled scrollbar - https://jsfiddle.net/4scqnpy5/2/

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use : chart.xAxis[0].setCategories
as following:

```
var objData2 = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

            Highcharts.stockChart(wrappedResult[0], options, function(chart){
                $scope._chart = chart;
                $scope._chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'four', 'five' , 'six', 'seven']);
                //test
                $scope._chart.addSeries({
                    color: 'red',
                    data: _.cloneDeep(objData2)
                });

            });
```